# How can I apply I18N to the labels of a CheckboxSelectMultiple in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-i18n

Considering a Django application, I have to apply I18N to the values stored in "Area" table. The values of the field **i18n_code** points to *msgid* entries in my locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/django.po.

As you can see in my code, Startup model has a ManyToMany field of Area. In my form, *area* is a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget. How can I, inside my form01.html (template) get the **i18n_code**, pass to `{% trans area.i18n_code %}` so I can get options rendered in proper language?

I checked many questions relative to this subject... but I did not got some clean solution.

Checkout the codes:

**models.py**:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Area (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    i18n_code = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Startup (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    # ...
    areas = models.ManyToManyField(Area, verbose_name = 'Areas')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**form01.html**

```
<div class="row linhaForm">
    <div class="col-lg-4 legenda">
        <b>{% trans 'FORM_1_LABEL_AREA' %}</b>
        <p>{% trans 'FORM_1_LABEL_AREA_DESCRIPTION' %}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        {% for area in form.areas %}
            <div class="checkbox">
                {{area}} <-------------------- Here is my problem!
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Step1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Startup
        fields = ['name', 'areas']
        widgets = {
            'areas': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'onclick':'onAreaCheckHandler()'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'name': {
                'required': _("FORM_1_ERROR_NAME_REQUIRED")
            },
            'areas': {
                'required': _("FORM_1_ERROR_AREA_REQUIRED")
            }

        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Step1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['areas'].queryset = models.Area.objects.all()
```

If you help me with this cenario, will help with the other that I have, where I got CharField with choices and ForeignKey fields too, rendered in a **Select** tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would fix your problem.

```
{% for area in form.fields.areas.queryset %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        {% trans area.i18n_code %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Blackeagle52! You really solved my problem! I'll have to write more code... but I have domain over it. I'd like to have something more manageable.. creating widgets or something like that. For now I'll use your solution. If I get to something inside ModelForm class... I'll post here!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question to show you my solution after Blackeagle52 help! 
(I was thinking... It was like programing **PHP** or **ASP** back in 2004)

For fields that have a *queryset* and widget *CheckBoxSelectMultiple*:

```
{% for area in form.fields.areas.queryset %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_areas_{{area.id}}">
            <input id="id_areas_{{area.id}}" name="areas" type="checkbox" value="{{area.id}}" {% if area.id in form.areas.value %} checked="checked" {% endif %}>
            {% trans area.i18n_code %}
        </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For fields that have *choices* parameter (tuple of 2 values) and widget *Select*:

```
<select class="form-control" id="id_type_register" name="type_register">
    {% for type in form.fields.type_register.choices %}
        <option value="{{type.0}}" {% if type.0 == form.type_register.value %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>
            {% trans type.1 %}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

In both cases, if needed, just change *queryset* by *choices* and user your model properties (e.g. name, i18n_code, slug...) to be rendered. In case of tuples like `[('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two'), ('3', 'Three')]` the model properties will be replaced by .0 or .1 after the name of the declared var in for statement.

Comment: Indeed, this way you can loop over your choices. You could do `for value, label in ...` for readability. Also pay attention with `.value`, as you could have some weird things, like ints vs strings.